# fetch-blob-not post image not wroking with Laravel api - react native

Tags: laravel, api, react-native, file-upload, react-native-fetch-blob

I need help , i have working with react native and api laravel to upload image but not uploading ?

**this my react native code**

```
    var dataphoto = this.state.photoData; // this from ImagePicker
    RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'my_url/api/storimage', {
      Authorization : "Bearer access-token",
      otherHeader : "foo",
      'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
    }, [
      { name : 'image', filename : 'image.jpg',type:'image/jpg', data: dataphoto},
    ]).then((resp) => {
      console.log('response: ' + JSON.stringify(resp));
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('err: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    })
```

**This My Laravel Code**

```
// Route::post('storimage','apiController@storimage');  **api route**
   public function storimage(Request $req){ // the function
   if($req->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $image = $req->file('image');
        $name = time().'.' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
        \Image::make($req->file('image'))->save(public_path('images/').$name);
        return response()->json('Successfully yes');
    } 
    else{
            return response()->json('not');
    }
}
```

**Whay my code not working!**

Comment: did you find any solution, I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You send the data image, so in server recieve a base64, you can:

```
$base64Image = $req->get('image');
$data = base64_decode($base64Image);
file_put_contents($imagePath, $data);
```

$imagePath is where you save